# Not able to open text file via File System Object in VAPI test case in QC

Tags: vbscript, filesystemobject, hp-quality-center, vapi

I am trying to read a config file in my VAPI test case in QC.
Following is the code snippet:

```
Set objFSO =CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile=objFSO.OpenTextFile(strFileName,1)
strText = objFile.ReadAll
objFile.Close
```

However I am getting the following error: Operation is not allowed when the object is closed.

I am able to use the same code if run it from outside of QC in simple .vbs file.Can anyone please help me out with this.
Thanks

Comment: Maybe a variable name collision? Try another name for `objFile` (add appropriate prefix or suffix) or make it's scope local explicitly using `Private` statement. Supposedly the same for `objFSO`...

Comment: Hi, I already tried both of these suggestions..not working...I have just declared these variables once in the VAPI test. Do you think this can be any QC specific issue ?